# Passing arguments to a new viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, segue

When I am segueing to a new viewController, a would like to pass an argument, let's say "turnId" to a new `ViewController`. I know I can do this in the `prepareForSegue` method, but how can I pass the argument to the `prepareForSegue` method itself? How can I get this from the sender? The sender is `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, but the value is not residing in a cell, but just declared in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` like:

```
String *turnId = @"123";
```

Comment: This might help you: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-and-other-objects-link-fixed.html

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't pass it in the sender info.

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` do your `[self performSegueWithIdentifire:@"blah"]` and then in `prepareForSegue` do something like this...

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:... //blah cant remember the name
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"blah"]) {
        NewViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        //get the object associated with that row and set a variable like...
        NSString *selectedString = tableObject.name;

        //Then pass the string into the controller...
        controller.stringProperty = selectedString;
    }
}
```

Then in `NewViewController.h` set up a `@property` to accept this...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *stringProperty;
```

Then you can access this value from `NewViewCongtroller.m` and it will have the value passed in to it.

Comment: Ok, but then how do I get the NSString value out of the "selectedIndexPath" variable? Do I need it to temporarily save it in a cell or so? Is this "tableObject" what you mean by a cell?

Comment: Also, I see that indexPathForSelectedRow returns nil outside of didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I presume in didSelectRowAtIndexPath you are doing something to calculate what this string should be and that is how you are getting @"123".  Well, just do that in prepareForSegue instead.

Comment: Oh, and indexPathForSelectedRow doesn't return nil outside didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  I use it all the time for exactly this reason.